# Laravel mutator or creating event

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I have two models, `Card` and `Expense`. Both have a `type` field. Whenever I add a new expense, I have a dropdown in the form to select a `Card`. They are related by a belongsTo relation.

The thing is, I want to automatically set the `type` field of my Expense to the same as my card's type. I do not want to have another dropdown for `type` in my expense form. Also, I want to keep using the following on my `store` method on my Expense Controller:

```
auth()->user()->expenses()->create($request->all());
```

I think this should be possible by using a mutator perhaps in the model, but I'm not entirely sure how to approach this.

So in short, what I need is, when creating a new `Expense`, I need the `type` field to be grabbed from the related `Card`, and then inserted into the `Expense type` field.

What I don't want to do in my controller, is something like:

```
$expense = new Expense;
$expense->name = ... And so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `type` from the Card model, you could do something like this:

```
$card = Card::find(1);
$card->expenses()->create(array_merge($request->all(), ['type' => $card->type]));
```

But it's not a good idea to duplicate `type` if you already have one in the Card model and Expense belongs to Card.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I was thinking of the best solution for my app, so I will probably have to re-think this, but for now, this should do it, thanks :)